# How to select all hosts except the inventory_hostname from a group?

Tags: ansible

I have a group of two hosts. I want to delegate a task to the one that is not the current host.

The following doesn't match anything and just returns a list of my initial two hosts.

```
  - debug: msg="{{ groups['web-servers'] | select('match', '^(?!\{\{\ inventory_hostname\ \}\}$).+') | list }}"
```

I think it's escaping that's the issue but I can't figure it out.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

An option would be to use the [*difference*](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/devel/user_guide/playbooks_filters.html#set-theory-filters) filter. Below is an example of how to use the filter

```yaml
shell> cat test-difference-01.yml
- hosts: localhost
  gather_facts: no
  vars:
    web_servers:
      - web-server-01
      - web-server-02
      - web-server-09
    inventory_hostname:
      - web-server-02
  tasks:
    - set_fact:
        delegate_to_hosts: "{{ web_servers|difference(inventory_hostname) }}"
    - debug:
        msg : "{{ delegate_to_hosts }}"
```

```yaml
shell> ansible-playbook test-difference-01.yml | grep -A 3 msg
    "msg": [
        "web-server-01", 
        "web-server-09"
    ]
```

---

Q: **"*group of two hosts ... delegate a task to the one that is not the current host*"**

Given the inventory

```yaml
shell> cat hosts
[webservers]
web-server-01
web-server-02
```

The playbook

```yaml
- hosts: webservers
  tasks:
    - debug:
        msg: "{{ inventory_hostname }} {{ item }}"
      loop: "{{ groups.webservers|difference([inventory_hostname]) }}"
      delegate_to: "{{ item }}"
```

gives (abridged)

```yaml
ok: [web-server-01 -> web-server-02] => (item=web-server-02) => 
  msg: web-server-01 web-server-02
ok: [web-server-02 -> web-server-01] => (item=web-server-01) => 
  msg: web-server-02 web-server-01
```

The code can be generalized by running on *all* hosts listed in [*ansible_play_hosts_all*](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/reference_appendices/special_variables.html#special-variables)

```yaml
- hosts: all
  tasks:
    - debug:
        msg: "{{ inventory_hostname }} {{ item }}"
      loop: "{{ ansible_play_hosts_all|difference([inventory_hostname]) }}"
      delegate_to: "{{ item }}"
```

Answer (score 3):

You don't need to specify a regex with negative lookahead. Instead, use the [`reject` filter](http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/2.10/templates/#reject).

Also, with `equalto` test, you don't need to enclose the string in `^` and `$`:

```
- debug:
    msg: "{{ groups['web-servers'] | reject('equalto', inventory_hostname) | list }}"
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is with the variable substitution (or lack thereof) in the regex pattern. You can define the pattern separately, and pass that to the filter (note that I did modify your regex a bit):

```
- set_fact: pattern="^(?!{{ inventory_hostname }}).+$"
- debug: msg="{{ groups['web-servers'] | select('match', pattern) | list }}"
```

Result:

```
TASK [debug : debug] ******************************************
ok: [foo] => {
    "msg": [
        "bar",
        "baz"
    ]
}
ok: [bar] => {
    "msg": [
        "foo",
        "baz"
    ]
}
ok: [baz] => {
    "msg": [
        "foo",
        "bar"
    ]
}
```